# Pass the current class type to typeOf in an interface

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I created an interface class to put all the commun methods then i inherit from my other class, however i am finding an issue with a method i use to check the attributes of said class

```
    public KeyValuePair<string, string> CheckForNonNullArguments()
    {

        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(BaseBLL).GetProperties();
        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property in properties)
            if (property.GetValue(this, null) != null && (!property.GetValue(this, null).Equals("NULL") && !property.GetValue(this, null).ToString().Equals("0")) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(property.GetValue(this, null).ToString()))
                return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(property.Name.ToString(), property.GetValue(this, null).ToString());
        return new KeyValuePair<string, string>("", "");
        //if (property.GetValue(this, null) != null) GetName(() => property); ;
    }
```

"BaseBLL" is the name of the interface class, and i need to change it each time i inherit, is there a way to do so ? i tried the Activator but it doesnt work or i didnt know how to use it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pass a `Type` to your method and when calling it `CheckForNonNullArguments(typeof(BaseBLL))`will do the job

Comment: Thank you very much  (can't vote yet ^^")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this :

```
public KeyValuePair<string, string> CheckForNonNullArguments(Type @class)
{

    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = @class.GetProperties();
    foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        object val = property.GetValue(this, null); // Caching result for better perfs.
        string str = val?.ToString();
        if (val != null && (!str.Equals("NULL") && !str.Equals("0")) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)
            return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(property.Name.ToString(), str);
    }
    return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(string.Empty, string.Empty);
    //if (property.GetValue(this, null) != null) GetName(() => property); ;
}
```

Called : `CheckForNonNullArguments(typeof(BaseBLL))`

Or even better :

```
public KeyValuePair<string, string> CheckForNonNullArguments<T>() where T : class
{

    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        object val = property.GetValue(this, null); // Caching result for better perfs.
        string str = val?.ToString();
        if (val != null && (!str.Equals("NULL") && !str.Equals("0")) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)
            return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(property.Name.ToString(), str);
    }
    return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(string.Empty, string.Empty);
    //if (property.GetValue(this, null) != null) GetName(() => property); ;
}
```

Called : `CheckForNonNullArguments<BaseBLL>()`

Comment: Even better thank you very much :D i sent hours with it ^^"

Comment: Note how the answer caches the return value of `GetValue`; this is important. Reflection is slow especially when called over and over. This applies to anything that performs the same calculation multiple times (same inputs, expecting the same outputs) You wouldn't write `if (Add(1,1)!=3 && Add(1,1)!=14 && Add(1,1) != 25){...} `, especially if `Add()` performed a big calculation. `int result=Add(1,1);  if (result !=3 && result!=14 && result !=25){...} ` See the difference? Depending on how much this is called it may benefit by caching the reflection in a delegate, but that's another question.

Comment: Also: there is an error in the answer. In both methods, it calls `val.ToString()` before testing if `val` is `null` and would throw a NRE. I'd change it to `string str = val.?ToString(); if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) && !str.Equals("NULL") && !str.Equals("0")) return new KeyValuePair<string,string>(property.Name, str);` (note `IsNullOrEmpty` does the null test, don't need it twice). Depending on your needs (and possible inputs) you may want to consider `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` instead and possibly specify case sensitivity options when using `Equals` against the string "NULL"

Comment: @pinkfloydx33: Ok for your first comment (I edited my answer) but not for the second one. I though so at the beginning but what if the prop is a class that's non null and in `.ToString()` methods it decides returns `null`? You won't get the prop still it's non-null.